# bad interpreter issue with Github

Tags: python, git, bash, github, flask

I am currently working on a team project and testing Twilio's API out in our project. I input "python3 run.py" in terminal and I got

> "No Flask Module".

So I input "pip3 install flask" in my virtual environment and I got

> -bash: /Users/(name)/Github Repos/(repo name)/development/bin/pip: "/Users/(name)/Github: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I have no clue why this is throwing this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to run `sudo -H pip3 install flask`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error message, this is clearly due to the space in your interpreter path (the space in `Github Repos`). If you look at the contents of your pip executable, you'll see that the shabang line includes the full path to the python executable, wrapped in quotes if there's a space in the path, like this:

```
#!"/Users/zmwang/.pyenv/virtualenvs/two words/bin/python3.5"
```

This form of shebang is recognized on Linux (tested on Ubuntu), but it's illegal on OS X (tested in bash and zsh — both greeted me with interpreter error). I don't know if there's a solution, but having whitespace in paths is always a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Yup, there was a blank and it was causing a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method of invoking Pip is

```
python -m pip
```

This ensures that the expected Python interpreter is invoked. Change your command to the following and you should be good to go.

```
python3 -m pip install flask
```